# clipboard copy is not working well sometimes

Tags: clipboard

OS : Windows 10, V 1703


My clipboard copy is not working well.

There is no any condition to happen problem.


When i copy english, there is no problem.

When i copy korean or etc not english more than two words, there is problem sometimes.



case 1. copy "AAAA" then set text in clipboard "AAAA"

case 2. copy "家家" then set text in clipboard "家家"

case 3. copy "家家家" then set text in clipboard "?"

case 3 is not happen always. just sometimes !




after it occur once then clipboard get "?" wherever and whenever.

even notepad, ms word, powerpoint, excel etc.


If i reboot my computer, then it works well during some minutes.

i don't know it's reason.

Thank you for watching.

Comment: You need to update Windows. Build 1703 is no longer serviced by Microsoft and you need to update it. As a bonus, your problem will probably be fixed if you update your computer.

Comment: Thank you @music2myear i will do that